# Codeigniter- Ajax Codeigniter Ajax -Retrurning more than one row through ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

how do i retrieve multiple rows from database table and access it in view file through controller :)

I am using AJAX to retrieve the data 
MY VIEW FILE:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".listproduct".click(function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?=site_url("purchasecont/getproductlist"; ?>',
        data: {'data' : value} ,
        success:function(result){
         console.log(result);
         for(i=0;i<result['count'];i++){
            var table = $('#products'); 
    var tr = (
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>'+ result[i]['invoiceno']; +'</td>'+
    '<td>'+ result[i]['price']; +'</td>'+
    '</tr>'
     );
  $('#products').append(tr);

         }
    }

    });
 $(".collapse".collapse('toggle');

});
});
</script>
```

MY CONTROLLER FILE : i will be retrieving more than one row from the table

```
public function getproductlist(){
//check if is an ajax request
if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
    //checks if the variable data exists on the posted data
    if($this->input->post('data')){


    $query = $this->purchasemodel->getproductlist($this->input>post('data'));
         $data['records'] = $query['records'];
        $data['count'] = $query['count']; 
          $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
        return $data;
                }
    }
  }
```

MY MODEL FILE : i will be retrieving more than one row from the table

```
 public function getproductlist($q){
  $this->db->select('*');    
    $this->db->from('purchaseprolist');
   $this->db->where('purchaseprolist.invoice' , $q);
    $this->db->where('purchaseprolist.price != ',0,FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $row = $query->result();
    return array(
'records' => $row,
'count' => count($row),
);

}
```

My Table to display the data: 
I am clueless how to display it here help me through please

```
<table id="products">                                
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Invoice</td>
            <td>price</td>
            <td id="quantity"></td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result you are retrieving from database have more than one element, you need to use loop in your view in order to populate the html with elements(ex. DataTable). Your code should looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".listproduct".click(function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?=site_url("purchasecont/getproductlist"; ?>',
        data: {'data' : value} ,
        success:function(result){
             for(i=0;i<result.length;i++){//loop trough elements
               $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + $('#invoiceno').html(result[i]['invoiceno']); + '</td><td>' + $('#productname').text(result[i]['productname']); + '</td><td>' + $('#price').text(result[i]['price']); + '</td></tr>');
             }
        }
    });
 $(".collapse".collapse('toggle');

});
});
```

Comment: Be cautious about the returning results from model in your view, for example if you returning JSON from the ajax request, you need firstly to deserialize the result before using it in loop and html.

Comment: i am sorry but how do i display this in a table of rows :) i donno how to access the ajax result and use it :)

Comment: and how do i deserialize it ?

Comment: use console.log(result); and see the structure of the results.
If you want to create html table, use javascript to generate the html dynamically.

Comment: i did it i will update it above :) just check if i am doing it right

Comment: actually its not working yet can you have a look at my updated code and guide me :)

Comment: You are using ids on the td tags, and in your solution you are replacing all the elements with the new one and in the end you will see only the last record in the table.
I have updated my answer, and that is how you can insert new rows.

Comment: thank you i updated but i guess i am not getting the result from model or controller file :(

Comment: then you need to start from the model, use var_dump(); function with the result as argument, and see where is your problem, then go to controller and do the same, after that you will use the above code to show the result in front end. :)